# Difference Blend in PS different from that in Gimp

Tags: photoshop, gimp

I've developed a workflow supporting diffuse/specular separation for isolating specular information from cross-polarized and co-polarized photography, this used in photogrammetry. I started this in Gimp, but then had moved to Photoshop, was surprised to see the difference blend behaving very differently from that in Gimp. I can post examples if need be, but I ended up going with subtract blend, which I believe is correct anyway (color+specular from co-polarized - color only from cross-polatized = isolated specular). I'm just curious why the difference with difference.

Comment: Two different dev teams with own understanding of the meaning and mathematics behind different blending modes. And this is the result.

Comment: Why does Colonel Sanders' fried chicken taste different from Mrs. Winner's fried chicken? Because they use different methods to cook it.